# libsvm predict same values for all

Tags: matlab, svm, libsvm

i am trying for libsvm in matlab. i have created a model for binary class. but it gives same predicted label throughout. how to build probabilistic classifier.  what should be the string '-s -g -t -b.....''?. I have taken feature vectors of images for training and testing. I have taken 216 images for training (24orig + 192dist). 46 for testing(5orig+41dist). I have to predict two class original and distorted i.e. 1 and 2.

i am trying for following:
1) %Train the SVM
  svmstruct = svmtrain1(label, Training, '-s 0 -t 2 -c 1 -g 0.833 -b 1');
  % Use the SVM model to classify the data
 [predict_label, accuracy, prob_values] = svmpredict(label, Test, svmstruct, '-b 1');
  it gives following error:
Length of label vector does not match # of instances.

while using this:
2) svmstruct = svmtrain1(label, Training, '-s 0 -t 2 -c 1 -g 0.833 -b 1');
  % Use the SVM model to classify the data
 [predict_label, accuracy, prob_values] = svmpredict(testlabel, Test, svmstruct, '-b 1');

it gives same predicted label i.e. 2